# Position of a particular substring in an imported HTML file

Tags: string-manipulation

```
data4 = {{"050318", "111529"}}

Do[
 ID2 = data4[[i, 2]];
 s = Import["http://www.swift.ac.uk/xrt_curves/00" <> ID2, "Text"];
 s = StringSplit[s, "\n"];
 line = Position[s, "Flux Light Curve"],
 {i, 1, Length[data4]}]
```

The `StringSplit` works properly, but when I want to identify the position it gives
line `{}` empty
I expect instead a number like
`{{106}}` for example

Even when I try with

```
Do[
 ID2 = data4[[i, 2]];
 s = Import["http://www.swift.ac.uk/xrt_curves/00" <> ID2, "Text"];
 s = StringSplit[s, "\n"];
 line = StringPosition[s, "Flux Light Curve"],
  {i, 1, Length[data4]}]
```

it gives me not a single line, but many empty ones.

Answer (score 8):

The string `"Flux Light Curve"` does not appear as an element of `s`.  If you are looking for a substring you will need a different function.

If you only want to know the positions of strings which contain `"Flux Light Curve"` as a substring, you might use:

```
Position[ s, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, __ ~~ "Flux Light Curve" ~~ __] ]
```

In this `~~` stands for [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html).

The output from this:

```
StringPosition[s, "Flux Light Curve"]
```

is a list with many empty lists as elements, because most elements in `s` do not contain the substring.  You can further process the result as needed.  For example:

```
x = StringPosition[s, "Flux Light Curve"];

Position[x, {__Integer}]

DeleteCases[x, {}]
```

Comment: Was looking at this answer related to a separte Q on querying key patterns. Why does StringMatchQ complain in v11 while giving the correct answer? `Position[{"ab", "bc", "ac", "be"}, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, "b" ~~ __]]`  >> `StringMatchQ::strse: String or list of strings expected at position 1 in StringMatchQ[List,b~~__].`

Comment: @alancalvitti By default `Position` looks at all parts of the expression, including heads, in this case `List`.  See [(7692)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7692/121), [(67100)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67100/121).  Simple solution: only pass expressions that match `_String` to `StringMatchQ`: `Position[{"ab", "bc", "ac", "be"}, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "b" ~~ __]]`—this is more general than adding `Heads -> False`.

Answer (score 2):

Mr.Wizard's answer correctly identifies why your code wasn't working: you needed `StringPosition` rather than `Position`, and then to delete the empty cases.

I wonder if there isn't another way to attack your problem. You are importing an HTML file, so why not use that fact rather than treat it as plain text? You don't actually need all the HTML markup. So instead consider:

```
ss = Import["http://www.swift.ac.uk/xrt_curves/00111529", "HTML"];
```

This strips out the extraneous HTML stuff. So the first 100 characters are:

```
StringTake[ss, 100]
```

> ```
> "Skip banner and navigation tools .  
>
>    Dept. of Physics & Astronomy  
>   XROA  
>     US Site | "
> ```

Contrast this with

```
s = Import["http://www.swift.ac.uk/xrt_curves/0000111529", "Text"];
StringTake[s, 100]
```

> [image]

(I had to insert this as a picture because inserting an HTML DOCTYPE statement really doesn't seem to work nicely with the StackExchange software, and rightly so!)

As you can see, you can obtain the positions of the desired substring within the whole, without having to split the string first.

```
StringPosition[ss, "Flux Light Curve"]
```

> `{{1797, 1812}, {2435, 2450}, {2465, 2480}}`

Of course, you can always `StringSplit` in the same way and find the substring that contains the sub(sub)string:

```
sss = StringSplit[ss, "\n"];
StringPosition[sss, "Flux Light Curve"]
```

> ```
> {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
> {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {{52, 67}},
>    {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
>    {}, {}, {{1, 16}, {31, 46}}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
> ```