# Trouble with Position[]

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages

I am in trouble with Position,
Although my example works as expected it throws a warning.

```
Position[{{a,b},{a,c},{a,b}}, _?(#[[2]]==b&), {1}]
```

> During evaluation of In[23]:= Part::partd: Part specification
>   List[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>

```
  (*Out[23]= {{1},{3}}*)
```

Whats wrong here (MMA 7) ?

Ok, have just realized that adding `Heads->False` helps

```
Position[{{a,b},{a,c},{a,b}}, _?(#[[2]]==b&), {1}, Heads->False]
```

But why is this necessary I allready have specifyed a levelspec of {1} so the Head should be ommited anyway.

Regards Robert

Comment: From *Mathematica* Help: With the default option setting `Heads->True`, `Position` includes heads of expressions, *and* their parts. BTW, the answer given by @YvesKlett will not produce such warning.

Comment: @hengxin I removed my comment because it was not answering the question, but for the record: `Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {_, b}]` or keeping the levelspec similar `Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {_, b},{1}]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 3):

```
Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, _?(#[[2]] == b &), {1}, 
 Heads -> False]
```

The default option is `Heads-> True`, which means that `_?(#[[2]] == b &)`  is applied to the head of `{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}`, that is to say `List`

Why is `_?(#[[2]] == b &)` applied to the Head in your example ? : because the Head is at level {1}

By convention in Mathematica, the Head of a expression `exp` is `exp[[0]]`.
`exp[[0]]`  is at level {1}, because `exp[[0]]` has only one indice.

Comment: Ok, but why is this neccessary?
I have specifyed levelspec of {1} that should be sufficient or ?

Comment: By convention in Mathematica, the Head of a expression `exp` is `exp[[0]]`

Comment: yes, I know but I explicitly specifyed {1} as levelspec so the Head should not be toched anyway

Comment: The Head options seems to be separate from the levelspec specification.  BTW it works the same in Cases when the option is set: `Cases[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, _?(#[[2]] == b &), {1}, Heads -> True]`

Answer (score 1):

Ok got now the final explanation from Markus van Almsick

As the Head of an Expression needs not to be an plain Symbol (e.g. List)
in aprticular the Head of an Expression can by it self be an (complicated) Expression the levelspec must and will apply also to the Head.
therefore the Head must be "turned off" for simple cases

very tricky.

Regards Robert

Answer (score 0):

Ok finaly figured out the "best" solution:

needs no Heads option and no levelspec.

Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {_, _?(#==b &)}]

thx for all posts

Comment: Whats wrong with `Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}}, {_, b}]`?

Comment: @Robert, look at Yves Klett comment. his solution is better than this one:)

Comment: Hi the example was just a simplification of my real problem:

actualy I want to compare a scalare to the Norm of the second list pair.


indta[[Flatten@Position[dta, {_, _?(Norm@# <= tol &)}]]]

Comment: Also note that, if, say, `b = 0`, a pattern `{_, b}` will not match `{a, 0.}` but the pattern test `{_, _?(# == b &)}` will match it.  Also if `b = 1. - 10^-15`, `{a, 1.}` will match `{_, _?(# == b &)}` but not `{_, b}`.  So there are some differences when working with numeric expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can easily appear with elements that are not heads, therefore `Heads -> False` is not a complete solution:

```
Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, d}, _?(#[[2]] == b &), {1}, Heads -> False]
```

> Part::partd: Part specification d[[2]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>
> ```
> {{1}, {3}}
> ```

So long as the unevaluated form e.g. `d[[2]]` will not result in a false match in your test this message could be ignored, and silenced with [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html).  More robustly simply check that the [`Length`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Length.html) of the element is long enough before attempting the extraction:

```
Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, d}, _?(Length[#] >= 2 && #[[2]] == b &), {1}]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {3}}
> ```

One can also use a more specific pattern such as:

```
Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, d}, {_, __}?(#[[2]] == b &), {1}]

Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, d}, {_, _?(# == b &), ___}, {1}]

Position[{{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, b}, d}, {_, x_ /; x == b, ___}, {1}]
```