# "Part specification is longer than depth" warning in Position function

Tags: list-manipulation, warning-messages, curated-data, finance

I'm working on a project which analyzes financial data. I download the price and dividend information for the SPY ETF which tracks the S&P 500:

```
price = FinancialData["SPY", "RawClose", {"Jan 1, 2010", "July 31, 2015"}]
div = FinancialData["SPY", "Dividend", {"Jan 1, 2010", "July 31, 2015"}]
```

I want to find what the prices on the dividend dates were:

```
index = Position[price, p_ /; MemberQ[div[[All, 1]], p[[1]]], 1]
```

That gives the correct result. However it also give an error message:

```
Part::partd: Part specification List[[1]] is longer than depth of object.
```

How can I get rid of that?

Comment: Use `Heads -> False`, that is `Position[price, p_ /; MemberQ[div[[All, 1]], p[[1]]], 1, Heads -> False]`

Answer (score 3):

Since [kirma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/3056/kirma) has pointed out the main trouble, which is also found in the potential duplicate [Trouble with Position[]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/67100/trouble-with-position), I thought I would add another alternative like [Bob Brooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5654/bob-brooks).

*Comment:*

Using [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) here instead of lists to manage your data might be more convenient.

We can convert the data* either with

```
pa = Association[Rule @@@ price];
da = Association[Rule @@@ div];
```

or

```
pa = AssociationThread[Rule @@ Transpose@price];
da = AssociationThread[Rule @@ Transpose@div];
```

You can look up the prices on the dividend dates or create a new association as follows:

```
Lookup[pa, Keys[da]]
(*
  {115.97, 111.73, 112.49, 124.3, 127.76, 127.05, 121.52, 121.59, 
   140.3, 134.14, 145.87, 142.79, 155.83, 159.07, 170.72, 181.56, 186.2, 
   195.94, 200.7, 206.52, 210.41, 210.81}
*)

KeyTake[pa, Keys@da]
(*
  <|{2010, 3, 19} -> 115.97, {2010, 6, 18} -> 111.73, {2010, 9, 17} -> 112.49,
    ...some lines omitted...
    {2014, 12, 19} -> 206.52, {2015, 3, 20} -> 210.41, {2015, 6, 19} -> 210.81|>
*)
```

*Note: Execute

```
Rule @@@ div
Rule @@ Transpose@div
```

to see what these do.  They restructure the lists into [`Rules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rules.html) that are used to associate a date with its corresponding value.

Answer (score 0):

Zoff, Try this

```
Table[Cases[price, {div[[i, 1]], __}], {i, 1, Length[div]}]
```

This will give you the price on the dividend date instead of the position.